# Suitable Zmq messsage pattern for communicating processes

Tags: python, ipc, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using **`pyzmq`** library to establish a communication between two python processes on the same machine. Looking at the available messaging patterns offered by ZMQ it is not clear which one is suitable.
In my case both processes need to send independently messages to one another at some random times. Basically at various moments each process is both a client and a server. Some visual description below.
[image]

To achieve this pattern, I am using two **`ZMQ.PAIR`** sockets. Each process **`.bind()`**-s a socket to receive on it and **`.connect()`**-s to the other to `.send()` whenever the need arises.
Similarly each has a dedicated thread to handle the receiving, which is blocking.

However this design seems to me a bit like a stretch and I'm wondering if there is a setup more natural and suitable for this scenario? I'm also imagining that it must be quite common.
In the current design I also do not like the fact that I need to manually take care of cleaning the two sockets when the processes finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nodes are literally identical (at least, in terms of how they view each other for communication purposes, i.e. no real "reliable" server to the others "transient" client) then you have two options:

**(A) Spin up two pairs of sockets, one pair that treats one node as a server and the other a client, and the other that reverses that relationship.**

This might be appropriate if the communication follows a strict pattern between the nodes, e.g. one node initiates the communication and there is a specific back and forth that occurs until the end of that particular conversation.  This allows each node to initiate communication independently and maintain their own communication cadence without confusing it with "crosstalk" initiated by the other node.

This is also more appropriate if there may some day be more than two nodes, to create a star topology where each node can communicate with every other node directly.  There's a limit to how many nodes this can reasonably work well with, beyond which you'll want to implement some sort of central broker.

**(B) Just pick one node to be the "server" and the other node to be the "client", `bind()` and `connect()` appropriately, and after that point just treat them as equals**

This sounds most like what you're looking for.  You don't *need* to be overly concerned with which side `bind()`s and which side `connect()`s.  At the moment it sounds as if you're opening and closing the connection every time you need to communicate.  You should consider just leaving the connection open for the life of your process.  The `PAIR` sockets you're using support completely unstructured communication, so you should feel free to send and receive from either direction regardless of which side you designate as your "server" and which side you designate as your "client".

Comment: In the A) case it is clear that 2 sockets are involved for each process. For the B) case it is not clear to me if you mean one or two sockets per process. One socket would imply that while a thread is waiting to receive on the socket, some other thread would attempt to write. If possible I would prefer this option since it's simpler to manage, but is is safe to use a zmq socket in such a way ?

Comment: ZMQ sockets are not thread safe, so you shouldn't be sharing a single socket between multiple threads (except under some limited conditions, if you know what you're doing, see [the 2nd question under here](http://zeromq.org/area:faq#toc6)). So, no, it's not safe. Do you *need* to use blocking receiving? There are options to not block. If you are blocking on your receiving socket, then that socket just needs to be dedicated to receiving and you'll need another socket for sending, unless I'm woefully misunderstanding your architecture.

Comment: I think I'll need to block. I cannot anticipate when the other process will send something. Unless I can register some callback for receiving/handling stuff.

Comment: I recommend you do some more reading on common setups in python - usually communication is handled in a loop that allows you to do a non-blocking receive attempt every tick. You'll see such a loop commonly in examples, though any additional work in the example is trivial. Using ZMQ in a blocking context is, so far as I've seen, uncommon.